# Express middleware type is not assignable

Tags: javascript, typescript, express

I have following error. I dont understand why my first, only the first, middleware is red underlined?

[image]

[image]

Could somebody guide me here? I am quite new to typescript.

Did i forgot something or?

Comment: And what did it say about other overloads?

Comment: @Anatoly well i actually does not inform myself what a overload is, or does in typescript

Comment: On the screenshot we see an error about first overload and a scrollbar

Comment: @Anatoly sorry but i have actually no clue what this error means. i still try to figure it out

Comment: I mean just scroll down and show what other errors there

Comment: @Anatoly okey, i have added it

Comment: Can you post both code pieces like a formatted text?

Comment: This piece of code compiles just fine:


function aaa(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Response | void {
        return null;
    }

    const router = Router();

    router.post('/', aaa);

Comment: @Anatoly i mean i could show you, but this error happens to literally every `app.use(...)`, every route.

Comment: and what is the difference between my eample with `aaa` and your handlers?

Comment: @Anatoly the problem is my computer or the packages. If i install my code on a different computer its gone

Comment: different version of TS maybe?

Comment: @Anatoly hmm they should be the same

Comment: @Anatoly they arent the same. 4.0.2 woks fine. 4.2.0-dev error appear

Comment: Is 4.2.0-dev an unstable version?

Comment: @Anatoly i thinkg yess. on their website 4.1 is planned on 17 november and i have the 4.2 dev.. idk why i have installed it with `npm i -g typescript`. however i will downgrade it to 4.0

Comment: @Anatoly thank you for your help. i have found the solution on my own

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to put the `RequestHandler` interface infront of my middleware methods

```
router.get('/dashboardOverview', <RequestHandler>authService.authentication, <RequestHandler>adminController.dashboardOverviewHandler)
```

And i also need to make sure that the handlers / middlewares always contains `Request`, `Response` and `NextFunction` in their callback